# Java - Get path of a file in my project

Tags: java, eclipse, file, path, filepath

I am working on a Java project (Eclipse IDE) which is using XWT files for UI purposes (which is basically an xml file). I need to dynamically edit one of those file during execution of the programm.

However, the project will not be executed from a definite directory and I need to get a relative path to the file.

So, say that my file is located under:

com.foo.goo.src.com.foo.goo.toto

Which translate on my disk by:

C:\\com.foo.goo\src\com\foo\goo\toto\file.xwt

But eclipse working directory is "C:\Eclipse\Workspace"

Is there a way to open this file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using FileResolve(URL url) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Paths` class and the `get` method, like  so:

```
Paths.get("C:\\file.txt").toFile()
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I have no way to know that the file will be in "C:\\file.txt". This is what I need to determine. The only thing I know is the file URL (not URI)

Comment: I tried to use the "Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile()" methods, but it throws a FileSystemNotFoundException.

I have a start of solution using "(url.toURI().getPath()).toFile().getAbsolutePath()" however the obtained path is not correct: if the file uri is \\com\\foo\goo\file.xwt, the absolute path I obtain at the end is C:\\com\\foo\\goo\\file.xwt, so everything between C:\\ and \\com is missing.